# Signature scanning

Tags: security, signature, malware-detection

many antivirus programs using signature-based malware detection. Here is [creating signatures for ClamAV](http://www.clamav.net/doc/webinars/Webinar-Alain-2009-03-04.pdf). I can understand how they create signatures considering that the whole file is a malware, but I couldn't understand how to find malware when it is in the body of the file - the hash would be another. Anybody knows?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**My answer is not specific to ClamAV; instead I've answered in a general sense.** Maybe this is helpful for you.

First of all a virus signature is not *necessarily* a hash value of a file. A *signature* is usually a string of bits found in a file, although a hash value could also be used as a signature.

Suppose, for example, that a virus contains the string of bits `0x23956a58bd910345`. We can consider this string to be a signature of the virus, and we can search for this signature in the files on a system. *However, even if we find the signature, we can’t be certain that we’ve found the virus, since other innocent files could contain the same string of bits.*

Its interesting to note that if the bits in files were random, the chance of such a false match would be negligible at 1/2^64. [reference](https://engineering.purdue.edu/kak/compsec/NewLectures/Lecture9.pdf)

There many ways to generate signature and/or features for malware detections. [Learn more here.](https://amanda-cle.info/zcvisitor/e6218045-c619-11ec-bff8-121fb804a59b/b71e37a0-18cb-11ea-9f38-0a157bfa6bfc?campaignid=2a82f030-bbe2-11ec-bea2-128084d1ce51)

Also, there is other way to detect viruses:
1 **Anomaly detection** - also known as **behaviour analysis** - tracks of activities of an executable like:

> - Modified or created files
> - Registry modification
> - Which DLLs were loaded before execution
> - Accessed virtual memory
> - Created processes
> - Network connections opened and the packets transmitted
> - What storage areas the malware accessed, installed services and kernel drivers as well as other information.
>   [reference](https://web.archive.org/web/20120731105522/http://0xbadcab1e.lu/papers/analyse.pdf)

2 **Change detection** - a file that unexpectedly changes may indicate an infection.

How can we detect changes? Hash functions are useful in this regard. Suppose we
compute hashes of all files on a system and securely store these hash values. Then, at
regular intervals, we can recompute the hashes and compare the new values with the
previously stored values. If a file has changed in one or more bit positions — as it might in the case of a virus infection — we'll find that the newly computed hash does not match the previously computed hash value.

There are many disadvantages to change detection. Files on a system often change due to normal system functions rather than malicious behaviour. As a result, change detection is likely to yield many false positives, which places a heavy burden on users and administrators. If a virus is inserted into a file that changes often, it will likely slip through a change detection regimen.
[reference: Mark-Stam's Book INFORMATION SECURITY]

**And you thinks correct hash mechanism is weak method to for detection**.
In my research work, I compared and classified more than 2000 real viruses using 14 antivirus tools and I found that ClamAV is very bad at detecting virus! Here is the link for a paper describing [MOMENTUM](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6207739).

[image: Graph showing the detection rates of various anti-virus products]

Comment: But ClamAv is open source, so we can see its codes ;) Could you recommend some literature or sources about Behaviour Analysis, because i couldn't understand the way it is working from what i found searching Google?

Comment: - Command is $: sudo apt-get source clamav. I feel you are new to Malware Analysis: Peter-Szor is best book to start with. Behaviour Analysis categorised under dynamic analysis. Read here: http://0xbadcab1e.lu/papers/analyse.pdf. Also read from computer virology. Which standard you are in?

Comment: Yes, I'm new to this. So, I'm not sure I understand what do you mean under standart, but thank you for reference to the book, it seems to be helpfull.

Comment: I mean what do you do? I would also like to recommend you learn ollyDBG, for Dynamic - Cuckoo & Ether http://ether.gtisc.gatech.edu/malware.html ...

Answer (score 0):

This project is developed based on the console user interface (CUI). It has own scanning algorithm for finding malicious code in each file during the scan. The core idea is to search/match the virus signatures in all scan files or directory. Usually, 90% of viruses/worm having own signature (Some repeat text founded in all affected binary files or archive files) and remain 10% Viruses are identified based on execution behavior.

Here I wrote code for signature-based scan algorithm, so I stored Virus signatures in separate databases and it organizes in file flat system format.
The main feature is without installation it can able to scan the system and it allows to scanning all file type extension including hidden files and hidden directories.

Please find the source code from my tech blog - http://www.algonuts.info/how-to-create-antivirus-using-c-programming.html

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<process.h>
#include<io.h>
#include<alloc.h>
#include<dir.h>
#include<ctype.h>

struct ffblk dblist,list;
FILE *temp_p,*dp,*vp;
char *sign =  (char *) malloc(9);

char ch;
unsigned int count,first=0,found=0;
unsigned long int start,udata1,udata2,udata3;

void set_virus_name(char *);
void update_signature(char *,char *,int,int);
void set_data(char *,char *,int);

void main()
{
    clrscr();
    char *vfile = (char *) malloc(40);
    char *dfile = (char *) malloc(40);
    cout<<"\nSystem: Enter the infected filename: ";
    cin>>vfile;

    if(access(vfile,0)!=0)
    {  
        cout<<"\nError : File not exist"; 
        free(sign);  
        free(vfile); 
        free(dfile); 
        getch(); 
        exit(0); 
    }
    strcpy(sign,"LITTLE17"); 

    udata1 = findfirst("*.db",&dblist,0);
    while (!udata1)
    {   
        first=1;
        temp_p= fopen(dblist.ff_name,"r");  
        fread(sign,8,1,temp_p); 
        if(!strcmp(sign,"LITTLE17"));
        update_signature(vfile,dblist.ff_name,1,0);  
        fclose(temp_p);
        udata1=findnext(&dblist);
    }

    if(first==0)
    {
        cout<<"\nSystem: Enter the database name :";
        cin>>dfile;
        udata1=strlen(dfile);
        if(dfile[udata1-3]=='\.'&& (dfile[udata1-2]=='D'||dfile[udata1-2]=='d') &&  (dfile[udata1-1]=='B'||dfile[udata1-1]=='b') )      
        update_signature(vfile,dfile,0,1); 
        else
        { 
            cout<<"\n\nError : Create .DB extension file type"; 
            free(sign); 
            free(vfile); 
            free(dfile); 
            getch(); 
            exit(0);  
        } 
    }
    else
    {
        if(found==0)  
        {   
            cout<<"\nSystem: Enter the database name :";
            cin>>dfile;
            udata1=strlen(dfile);
            if(dfile[udata1-3]=='\.'&& (dfile[udata1-2]=='D'||dfile[udata1-2]=='d') &&  (dfile[udata1-1]=='B'||dfile[udata1-1]=='b') )
            {
                if(!access(dfile,0))
                {   
                    dp = fopen(dfile,"r");  
                    fread(sign,8,1,dp); 
                    fclose(dp);
                    if(!strcmp(sign,"LITTLE17"))
                    update_signature(vfile,dfile,1,1); 
                    else
                    { 
                        cout<<"\n\nError : Database not supported with "<<vfile;  
                        free(sign); 
                        free(vfile); 
                        free(dfile); 
                        exit(0);  
                    }  

                }
                else
                update_signature(vfile,dfile,0,1); 
            }
            else
            {   
                cout<<"\n\nError: Create .DB extension file type"; 
                free(sign);  
                free(vfile); 
                free(dfile); 
                exit(0); 
            }  

        }
    } 
    free(sign);
    free(vfile); 
    free(dfile); 
    getch();
}

void update_signature(char *vfile,char *dfile,int check,int add)
{       
    if(check==1)
    {   
        char *temp = (char *) malloc(strlen(dfile)+1);
        strcpy(temp,dfile);
        char *turn = (char *) malloc(40+2+400+1);   

        dp = fopen(dfile,"r");
        fread(sign,8,1,dp); 
        fread(&start,sizeof(start),1,dp);
        while(1)
        {  
            udata1=0;     
            while(1)
            {
                ch=fgetc(dp);
                if(ch!=0 && ch!=32 && ch!='\n' && ch!='\t')
                {
                    if(ch==20)
                    udata2=udata1;
                    if(ch!=22)                  
                    {   
                        turn[udata1]=ch; 
                        udata1=udata1+1;
                        continue; 
                    }
                    else
                    break;
                }
            }  
            turn[udata1]='\0';
            udata2=udata2+1;
            udata3=udata2;

            count=0;
            udata1=0; 
            udata2=udata3;
            vp=fopen(vfile,"r");
            findfirst(vfile,&list,0);
            while(udata1<list.ff_fsize)
            {

                fseek(vp,udata1,SEEK_SET);
                ch=fgetc(vp);
                if(ch!=0 && ch!=32 && ch!='\n' && ch!='\t' && ch!= 20 && ch!= 22)
                {
                    if(ch!=turn[udata2])
                    {   
                        if(count>=2)
                        udata1=udata1-count;
                        count=0;
                        udata2=udata3;
                    }
                    else
                    {   
                        count=count+1;
                        udata2=udata2+1;
                        if(turn[udata2]==0)
                        {   

                            cout<<"\n\n\nError : Unsuccessfully ! ";
                            cout<<"\n\nError : Virus were Already added on "<<temp;  
                            cout<<"  [ ";
                            udata3--;
                            for(count=0;count<udata3;count++)
                            {
                                if(turn[count]!=32)
                                cout<<turn[count];
                                else
                                cout<<" ";                                  
                            }
                            cout<<" ]";
                            found=1; 
                            break; 
                        }           
                    }
                }                   
                fflush(vp);
                udata1=udata1+1;

            }
            fclose(vp);

            if(found==1)
            break;
            ch=fread(&start,sizeof(start),1,dp);
            if((ch+1)==1)
            break;
        }
        fclose(dp);
        free(temp);
        free(turn);

        if(found==0&&add==1)
        {
            set_data(vfile,dfile,check);   
        }                   
    }
    else
    {       
        set_data(vfile,dfile,check);    
    }                       
}


void set_data(char *vfile,char *dfile,int check)
{
    char *temp = (char *) malloc(40);
    cout<<"\n\nSystem: Set the name of virus :";
    gets(temp);
    cout<<"\nEnter first index :";
    cin>>udata1;
    start=udata1;
    cout<<"\nEnter last  index :";
    cin>>udata2;
    char *vdata = (char *) malloc((udata2-udata1)+2+2+2+1); 
    vdata[0]=20;
    udata3=1;

    vp=fopen(vfile,"r");
    while(udata1<=udata2)
    {   
        fseek(vp,udata1,SEEK_SET);
        ch=getc(vp);
        cout<<udata1<<" "<<ch<<"\n";
        if(ch!=0 && ch!=32 && ch!='\n' && ch!='\t' && ch!=20 && ch!=22)
        {
            vdata[udata3]=ch;
            udata3=udata3+1;    
            vdata[udata3]='\0';             
        }
        udata1=udata1+1;
    }
    fclose(vp);
    vdata[udata3+1]='\0';
    vdata[udata3]=22;

    dp=fopen(dfile,"a+"); 
    if(check==0)
    fwrite(sign,8,1,dp);
    fwrite(&start,sizeof(start),1,dp);
    fwrite(temp,strlen(temp),1,dp);
    free(temp);
    fwrite(vdata,strlen(vdata),1,dp);
    free(vdata);
    fclose(dp);
    cout<<"\n\nSystem: Successfully Added on "<<dfile;
}
```